# Отрисовка текста с помощью DrawThemeTextEx

Tags: c#, aeroglass, winforms, windows-aero

Привет всем.
Пишу контрол, наследующийся от стандартного Label и добавляющий в него поддержку Aero.
В [найденных исходниках](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/) творится Адъ и Израиль (собственно, потому и пишу свой).
Поясните, пожалуйста, процесс отрисовки от начала и до конца.
В частности, непонятно, зачем во всех примерах используются DIB sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы нашлись.
[Очень подробная статья на тему на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx)